# Javascript function returning undefined value in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, dom-events, asynccallback

I am writing code for getting data.
First I call `**getsomedata**` function to get data and inside **getsomedata** function I am calling another function **getRandomdata** to get data and returning it back to the previous function but it is returning `undefined`. But in `getRandomdata` data could be seen in `console.log`.
Do I need to use `callbacks` ?

```
router.get('/get-data', function (req, res, next) {
    var result = getsomedata(some_parameter);
    console.log(result);   // receiving undefined
    res.send(result);
});

function getsomedata(some_parameter_recieved) {
    var getsomedata = getRandomdata(random_params);
    console.log(getsomedata);    // receiving undefined
    return getsomedata;
}

function getRandomdata(random_params_recieved) {
    // after some calculation 
    console.log(random_data);           // receiving proper data
    return random_data;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to `asynchronous` programming! Read about `callbacks` or `Promise`

Comment: You probably need to return values from the `callback`. Try this  http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: yaha sure, but please can you make modify of this code? because its argent to me. if you don't mind.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Instead of `return`, you should use `callbacks` because in `asynchronous` operations, `return` does not wait for the `I/O` operation to complete.

**`Callback`** - In JavaScript, higher order functions could be passed as parameters in functions. Since JavaSCript is a single threaded, only one operations happens at a time, each operation thats going to happen is queued in single thread. This way, passed functions(as parameter) could be executed when rest of the parent functions operation(`async`) is completed and script can continue executing while waiting for results.

Usually this `callback` function is passed in as the last argument in the function.

**Using `Callbacks`:**

```js
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
  getsomedata(some_parameter, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});

function getsomedata(some_parameter_recieved, callback) {
  getRandomdata(random_params, function(random_data) {
    callback(random_data);
  });
}

function getRandomdata(random_params_recieved, callback) {
  // after some calculation
  callback(random_data);
}
```

**Using `Promise`:**

```js
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
  getsomedata(some_parameter, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});

function getsomedata(some_parameter_received, callback) {
  getRandomdata(random_params).then(function(random_data) {
    callback(random_data);
  }).catch(function(e) {
    //handle error here
  });
}

function getRandomdata(random_params_received, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // after some calculation
    if (RandomDataGeneratedSuccessfully) {
      resolve(random_data);
    } else {
      reject(reason);
    }
  });
}
```